# Expectation property of moment generating function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, moment-generating-functions, expected-value

Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable and define $M_X(t) := \mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]$. Suppose that $M_X(t) < \infty \mbox{ for all } t < \alpha$, where $\alpha > 0$.

[It can be shown](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/32787/49690) that this condition implies $\mathbb{E}[X^k]<\infty$ for all $k$, i.e. all moments exist.

How can we establish that $\mathbb{E}[X^ke^{tX}] < \infty$ for all $k$ and $ t < \alpha$?

Comment: My idea is to use tail property. Any expectation is integral (supposedly either in Stieltjes or in Lebesgue sense.) So you can divide your last expectation into the parts $[0 , \epsilon]$ and $[\epsilon , \infty)$. And then analyse the convergence properties. (In the first region it is for sure bounded), In tail regions it can be done intuitively. $e^{x}$ is faster then $dF_{X}(x)$ in tail, so $dF_{X}(x)= o(e^{-x})$, such that for no $k$, $e^{x}*x^{k}$ can be faster $dF_{X}(x)$.(This is acc. proof, when you have continuous random variable, but I'm not sure with general case(can have jumps)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t<t'<\alpha$. Then $e^{(t'-t)x} \geq \frac {(t'-t)^{k}x^{k}} {k!}$ so $x^{k}e^{tx} \leq \frac {e^{t'x} k!} {(t'-t)^{k}}$. Hence $EX^{k}e^{tX}\leq M(t') \frac { k!} {(t'-t)^{k}}<\infty$.